# UndefinedConversionError while using Windows Cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install an application using chef on a Windows machine. I am using the windows cook book. Here is the recipe.

```
windows_package 'MyInstaller' do
  source 'C:/ChefRepo/setup.exe'
  options '-ms'
  installer_type :custom
  action :install
end
```

I get the following error when I ran `chef-client –z –o testcookbook`

```
Running handlers:
[2016-02-20T15:40:47+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-02-20T15:40:47+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 minutes 29 seconds
[2016-02-20T15:40:47+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to

C:/Users/myusername/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-02-20T15:40:47+05:30] FATAL: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError:  
windows_package[MyInstaller] (testcookbook::default line 10) had an error:    
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+2122 to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-
16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437
```

Here is line number 10

```
 windows_package 'MyInstaller' do
```

Here is the content of the metadata.rb fie.

```
name             'testcookbook'
maintainer       'YOUR_COMPANY_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures testcookbook'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'
depends 'windows'
```

Why is it complaining about encoding? Can anyone give any helpful suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Try change your source path - source 'C:\\ChefRepo\\setup.exe'

Comment: I tried, but no luck, Here is the error i got. Encoding::Unde
finedConversionError: U+2122 to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437.

Comment: try change path with back slashes and also remove the installer_type

Comment: I tried, but no luck. I get the same error. U+2122 to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437.